# EF6 Required-to-Optional Relationship (One-to–Zero-or-One) not working correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a one-to-zero-or-one relationship and the problem that I'm running into is that the navigation property on the dependent entity to the principal entity is always null unless the principal entity is loaded first from its DbSet.

Database Relationship is Employee.ID -> TrainerProfile.TrainerID with TrainerID being the primary key and foreign key.

Entities are Employee.Id -> TrainerProfile.Id that is mapped with the [Column] attribute.

```
//Principal
public class Employee : BaseEntity<int>
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public override int Id { get; protected set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Username is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A First Name is required")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Last Name is required")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string LName { get; set; }
    ...
}

//Dependent
public class TrainerProfile : BaseEntity<int>
{   
    private TrainerProfile()
    {
    } 

    protected TrainerProfile(int id) : base(id)
    {
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("TrainerID")]
    public override int Id { get; protected set; }

    public bool Passport { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string SpecialConsiderations { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string SeatPreference { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}


//DBContext OnModelCreating()
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.TrainerProfile)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Employee);

modelBuilder.Entity<TrainerProfile>()
            .HasKey(e => e.Id)
            .HasRequired(e => e.Employee)
            .WithOptional(e => e.TrainerProfile);
```

**UPDATE**

```
var db = new DBContext();
var profile = db.TrainerProfiles.First(); //profile.Employee null
var employee = db.Employees.List(); //profile.Employee now loaded
```

Comment: Please show the code in which you see that "the principal entity is always null".

Comment: @GertArnold I've updated the example.

Comment: Unless lazy loading is disabled in the context `profile.Employee` should be loaded when it's accessed, either in code or in the debugger. So, is lazy loading disabled?

Comment: @GertArnold lazy loading is enabled. It was working previously but TrainerProfile.Id was TrainerProfile.TrainerID.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by changing the default constructor accessor from private to protected.

```
//Dependent
public class TrainerProfile : BaseEntity<int>
{   
    protected TrainerProfile() //***Changed from private to protected***
    {
    } 

    protected TrainerProfile(int id) : base(id)
    {
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("TrainerID")]
    public override int Id { get; protected set; }

    public bool Passport { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string SpecialConsiderations { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string SeatPreference { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```